# Add IP alias on macOS like on Ubuntu?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

I want to add a second IP address on my Mac like on Ubuntu.

On Ubuntu I use this:

```
$ sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.12/24 dev eth0
```

On my Mac I used this:

```
$ sudo ifconfig en0 alias 192.168.1.12/24
```

On Ubuntu every computer on my local network can reach 192.168.1.12, however on my Mac it's not the same behavior, I can reach the local IP only on the computer and not on the others.

Do you know what can be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you've created the alias on the correct interface? - Have you checked which interface connects to your local network? (is it for example a wired or wireless interface, etc.)

Comment: Your commands look correct, they're consistent w/ these here -http://osxdaily.com/2009/08/05/how-to-create-an-ip-alias-in-mac-os-x-using-ifconfig/. You may want to try doing the subnet mask broken out vs as CIDR notation, just an idea.

Comment: You need to be using `networksetup`.  Remember macOS ≠ Linux

Comment: The linked question isn't really a duplicate, because it only deals with setting an IP address, not adding another one. For this, you'll need to do `networksetup -duplicatenetworkservice` or `-createnetworkservice` to create a new "service" on the same hardware port, and only then use `networksetup -setmanual` to set the new service's address.